# Python and Applescript path of running application using a partial app name?

Tags: python, applescript

I'm writing a Python program (trying to stick to included modules) and need to obtain the path of an application that is opened/active on MacOS platform by only using part of the application name. (eg. using 'Acrobat' from 'Adobe Acrobat Reader DC'). What's the correct applescript code for this to get the path output in stdout? (If there's a better method on MacOS let me know).
(Note: Needs to be subprocess.run rather than subprocess.Popen in my case)

```
import subprocess

def get_window_path():
    cmd = """
        tell application "System Events",
          if (get name of every application process) contains "Acrobat" then
            return POSIX path of (path to ((get name of every application process) contains "Acrobat"))
          end if
        end tell
    """
    result = subprocess.run(['osascript', '-e', cmd], capture_output=True)
    return result.stdout

print(get_window_path())
```

Comment: Couldn’t you just skip the AppleScript subprocess and use `NSWorkspace` via the PyObjC bridge?

Comment: @red_menace I'll look into that option, haven't heard of it, would be great to see a solution of how it works if it's simple enough.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know anything about calling **AppleScript** from `python`, however...

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code* assumes you only have one *application* running that contains "Acrobat" in its *name*, otherwise you'll need to process the *list* returned from **System Events** in a `repeat` *loop*.

```applescript
tell application "System Events" to ¬
    set appAcrobatList to the ¬
        name of every application process ¬
        whose background only is false ¬
        and name contains "Acrobat"

if appAcrobatList is not {} then ¬
    return POSIX path of ¬
        (path to application ¬
            (first item of appAcrobatList))
```

Answer (score 1):

This following ***AppleScript*** solution will return the path of the app if it is running. It will also return the paths of all running instances of the app, if there is more than one (without the need for a `repeat` loop).

```
property singleAppPath : missing value
property multipleAppPaths : missing value

tell application "System Events"
    set searchedApps to a reference to ¬
        ((every application process) whose name contains "Acrobat" or ¬
            displayed name contains "Acrobat")
    if (count of searchedApps) is 1 then
        set singleAppPath to POSIX path of application file of searchedApps as text
    else if (count of searchedApps) > 1 then
        set multipleAppPaths to POSIX path of application file of searchedApps
    end if
end tell
```

Comment: BTW Searching for “Acrobat” by the name property on my system returns {} but displayed name returns results.  According to `System Events` it’s name is “AdobeReader”

Answer (score 1):

Instead of switching back and forth between Python and AppleScript, another option would be to keep everything in Python and use the built-in [PyObjC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PyObjC) bridge to access the Cocoa API.  AppleScript is fine for what it does, but in this case you don't really need to use it.

I’m not all that great at Python, but the following uses `NSWorkspace` with an `NSPredicate` filter (tested with standard Catalina and Big Sur installations - note that Apple uses older versions):

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python

from Cocoa import NSWorkspace, NSPredicate

appName = "Acrobat"
runningApps = NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().runningApplications()
predicate = NSPredicate.predicateWithFormat_("localizedName contains[c] '%s'" % appName)
results = runningApps.filteredArrayUsingPredicate_(predicate)

if results == []:
   print("Matching Application Not Found")
else:  # just get some values from the first match
   print(results[0].localizedName())
   print(results[0].bundleIdentifier())
   print(results[0].bundleURL().path())
```